# Python: Finding the row index of a value in 2D array when a condition is met

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array `PointAndTangent` of dimension 8500 x 5. The data is row-wise with 8500 data rows and 5 data values for each row. I need to extract the row index of an element in 4th column when this condition is met, for any `s`:

```
abs(PointAndTangent[:,3] - s) <= 0.005
```

I just need the row index of the first match for the above condition. I tried using the following:

```
index = np.all([[abs(s - PointAndTangent[:, 3])<= 0.005], [abs(s - PointAndTangent[:, 3]) <= 0.005]], axis=0)

i = int(np.where(np.squeeze(index))[0])
```

which doesn't work. I get the follwing error:

```
i = int(np.where(np.squeeze(index))[0])

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am not so proficient with NumPy in Python. Any suggestions would be great. I am trying to avoid using `for` loop as this is small part of a huge simulation that I am trying.

Thanks!

**Possible Solution**
I used the following

```
idx = (np.abs(PointAndTangent[:,3] - s)).argmin()
```

It seems to work. It returns the row index of the nearest value to `s` in the 4th column.

Comment: Do you want `np.argwhere(abs(PointAndTangent[:, 4] - s) <= 0.005)`?

Comment: I don't think this works. I am getting 0 for any `s`.

Comment: @ShubhamSubhnil. That's because the first row matches

Comment: I'm not really sure what's tripping you up, but hopefully my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. `np.where` is one of the most abused functions in numpy. Half the time, you really want `np.nonzero`, and the other half, you want to use the boolean mask directly. In your case, you want `np.flatnonzero` or `np.argmax`:

```
mask = abs(PointAndTangent[:,3] - s) <= 0.005
```

`mask` is a 1D array with ones where the condition is met, and zeros elsewhere. You can get the indices of all the ones with `flatnonzero` and select the first one:

```
index = np.flatnonzero(mask)[0]
```

Alternatively, you can select the first one directly with `argmax`:

```
index = np.argmax(mask)
```

The solutions behave differently in the case when there are no rows meeting your condition. Three former does indexing, so will raise an error. The latter will return zero, which can also be a real result.

Both can be written as a one-liner by replacing `mask` with the expression that was assigned to it.